# Session Times out with AD authentication on Jboss

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, active-directory, forms-authentication, session-timeout

I am implementing Active Directory authentication on an old EJB 1.1/webwork/jboss app and i have replaced this code with an API method for AD and now the application timesout as soon as I Login. here is the below code.

**Before AD:**

```
AuthenticationManager securityMgr = (AuthenticationManager) securityCtx.lookup("securityMgr");
  SimplePrincipal principal = new SimplePrincipal(_username);
  char[] passwordChars = null;
     if (_password != null)
         passwordChars = _password.toCharArray();
  securityMgr.isValid(principal, passwordChars);
```

**After AD:**

```
UserInfo userInfo = com.authenticate.SingleSignOn.userAuthentication ("https://urllink/webservice.asmx/userAuthentication", _username, _password, "appname", "DEV", isNotExternal);
```

so as soon as i login and i am redirected to a page which has the code below

```
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=/app/login.begin.action">
```

this in turn takes me to the java code below

```
if (!getRequest().getSession().isNew()) {
            getRequest().getSession().invalidate();
}
return SUCCESS:  ( In webwork it will take to waht ever page you put for success in properties file here it is login page)
```

The problem is as soon as i login using AD it redirects me to login page. i wanted to know if i am missing something here and please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem to be with one of other libraries in my project

Comment: I have another login class which is the Jboss configuration that needs to be changed as well. I did not know that at the time of posting this question and later found out and changed. it works perfectly well.